# How to send my custom amount calculated by JavaScript as amount to PHP form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

Here is my JS code which calculates the total amount:

```js
function calTotal() {
  var a = 250.0,
    b = 175.0,
    c = 90.0,
    d = 415.0,
    e = 225.0,
    f = 225.0,
    g = 225.0,
    h = 225.0;
  var sum = 0.0;

  if (booking_form.faat_item1.checked == true) {
    booking_form.faat_item1.value = a;
    sum += a;
  } else booking_form.faat_item1.value = 0;

  if (booking_form.faat_item2.checked == true) {
    booking_form.faat_item2.value = b;
    sum += b;
  } else booking_form.faat_item2.value = 0;

  if (booking_form.faat_item3.checked == true) {
    booking_form.faat_item3.value = c;
    sum += c;
  } else booking_form.faat_item3.value = 0;

  if (booking_form.osfa_item1.checked == true) {
    booking_form.osfa_item1.value = d;
    sum += d;
  } else booking_form.osfa_item1.value = 0;

  if (booking_form.osfa_item2.checked == true) {
    booking_form.osfa_item2.value = e;
    sum += e;
  } else booking_form.osfa_item2.value = 0;

  if (booking_form.osfa_item3.checked == true) {
    booking_form.osfa_item3.value = f;
    sum += f;
  } else booking_form.osfa_item3.value = 0;

  if (booking_form.osfa_item4.checked == true) {
    booking_form.osfa_item4.value = g;
    sum += g;
  } else booking_form.osfa_item4.value = 0;

  if (booking_form.osfa_item5.checked == true) {
    booking_form.osfa_item5.value = h;
    sum += h;
  } else booking_form.osfa_item5.value = 0;

  return sum;
}

function sendTotal() {
  var total = calTotal();
  return total;
}
```

This code calculates the result just fine, but I want this calculated result to be directly sent as amount to my PayPal, following is my button code:

```html
<form
  name="_xclick"
  action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
  method="post"
>
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xyz@xyz.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MT1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="sendTotal()" />
  <input
    type="image"
    src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    border="0"
    name="submit"
    alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"
  />
</form>
```

The business name has been changed, I try to use this `sendTotal()` directly, but PayPal gives format error, can anyone please help out how to send my JS calculated total as the amount to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute to your total element,   ie id='total',  and add this to your javascript
document.getElementById('total').value=sendTotal();
That should work.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little using my code.

Comment: OK, tried what you said, still same error landing on PayPal :(

Comment: Hmm. I forgot to tell you to remove the value attribute from your html, try that and see if anything happens.